# xcode No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode

xcodeでios開発を行っています。
ビルド時に以下のエラーが発生してビルドに失敗します。

> error: /Users/hoge/fuga.png: No such file or directory

現在はfuga.pngは使用しないのでhogeディレクトリから削除をしたのですがまだ上記のエラーが発生します。解決方法を教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 現在はfuga.pngは使用しないのでhogeディレクトリから削除をした

Xcode（のナビゲーターエリア）からではなく、直接ディレクトリからファイルを削除していませんか？
もしそうであれば、ナビゲーターエリアで画像ファイルの格納場所を展開すると「fuga.png」が残っていると思いますので、それを削除すれば解消すると思います。

あるいは、下記を参考にCopy Bundle Resourcesで確認した方が早いかもしれません。
※削除したファイル名が赤くなっていると思います。

[What's the Xcode “no such file or directory error”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167442/whats-the-xcode-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

> If you receive either of these annoying errors when building your
>   xcode app, something has corrupted in your project bundle.
>
> 1. Open your project in Xcode
> 2. Click on your project
> 3. Click on your project under Targets
> 4. Hit the build phases tab
> 5. Open “Copy Bundle Resources” near the bottom
> 6. Look for any resources listed in red!

----- コメント欄から転記 -----

> 1. Xcodeでプロジェクトを開く。
> 2. ナビゲーターエリアのプロジェクト(一番上にある)をクリックする。
> 3. メイン画面の2行目？にある項目を選択する。項目を選択するとTargetsが選択できるので、現在のプロジェクトを選択する。
> 4. メイン画面の2行目にBuild phasesタブが存在するのでそれをクリックする。
> 5. Copy Bundle Resourcesがあるのでそれを選択する。
> 6. 赤くなっている文字がリンク切れのリソースなのでそれを選択し、下にあるマイナスマークを選択する。

Comment: ありがとうございます。２つ目の方法で解決しました。
一応、知識共有のため日本語でやったことを説明します。英語の通りなのでしょうが。
1. Xcodeでプロジェクトを開く。私の場合MyGameというプロジェクトです。
2. ナビゲーターエリアのプロジェクト(一番上にある、私の場合MyGame Project)をクリックする。
3. メイン画面の2行目？にある項目を選択する。項目を選択するとTargetsが選択できるので、現在のプロジェクトを選択する。私の場合MyGame iOS
4. メイン画面の2行目にBuild phasesタブが存在するのでそれをクリックする。
5. Copy Bundle Resourcesがあるのでそれを選択する。
6. 赤くなっている文字がリンク切れのリソースなのでそれを選択し、下にあるマイナスマークを選択する。

Comment: @KensukeSato 無事解決されたとのことで何よりです。また、日本語での情報共有ありがとうございます。せっかくなので回答に転記させていただきました。